# Multiple input lose focus on click

Tags: html, input

I have a form containing address fields as such 
http://jsfiddle.net/DP3aw/2/

For some reason I have to put the address in multiple text inputs as it is now.

When you click on the 2nd or 3rd input, the focus will jump to the first text field, why is that happening? is there anyway I can prevent that? or do I have to use js/jQuery to stop it from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have the all of your `INPUT` elements inside the `LABEL` tag. Clicking on a label focuses the associated input. Since all of your inputs are inside the label, they all trigger it, causing the focus to jump to the first input (the one that is associated).

Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/DP3aw/3/

### Broken

```
<label for="OrgAddr"><span>Address<strong>*</strong></span>
<div><input id="OrgAddr" name="OrgAddr" type="text" class="required" value=""></div>
<div><input id="OrgAddr2" name="OrgAddr2" type="text" value=""></div>
<div><input id="OrgAddr3" name="OrgAddr3" type="text" value=""></div></label>
```

### Fixed

```
<label for="OrgAddr"><span>Address<strong>*</strong></span></label>
<div><input id="OrgAddr" name="OrgAddr" type="text" class="required" value=""></div>
<div><input id="OrgAddr2" name="OrgAddr2" type="text" value=""></div>
<div><input id="OrgAddr3" name="OrgAddr3" type="text" value=""></div>
```

### Possible Improvement

Here's a more semantically correct version that uses a `FIELDSET` for the general grouping and labels for each individual input. It also demonstrates how clicking on a label will focus its associated input element.

http://jsfiddle.net/njY3U/1/

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Address</legend>
    <label for="street1">Street 1</label>
    <div><input type="text" id="street1" /></div>

    <label for="street2">Street 2</label>
    <div><input type="text" id="street2" /></div>

    <label for="city">City</label>
    <div><input type="text" id="city" /></div>

    <!-- ETC -->
</fieldset>
```